Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values. when dbcontext.codeddata
I am calling the stored procedure from .NET Core:
[Authorize(Roles = "1,2,3")]
[HttpPost("SaveDocumentAndParties")]
public async Task<IActionResult> saveDocumentAndParties([FromBody] SaveDocumentParties sd)
{
    string jsondata = string.Empty;

    await _lock.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    using (var dbContext = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString = sd.ConnectionString;

        try
        {
            if (dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().Close();
            }

            // Open the connection
              
            var Title = Regex.Replace(sd.Title, @"\s+", "");
            var actionParam = new SqlParameter("@Action", "Save");

            var partiesHistoryJsonParam = new SqlParameter("@partiesHistoryJson", sd.arrayParties);
            var exportExtraHistoryJsonParam = new SqlParameter("@exportExtraHistoryJson", sd.customField);
            var fieldSettingsJsonParam = new SqlParameter("@FieldSettingsJson", sd.FieldSettings);
            var codingSessionDetailsParam = new SqlParameter("@CodingSessionDetails", sd.CodingSessionDetails == "undefined" || String.IsNullOrEmpty(sd.CodingSessionDetails) == true ? null : sd.CodingSessionDetails);
            var documentIdParam = new SqlParameter("@DocumentID", sd.Document_ID);
            var projectIdParam = new SqlParameter("@ProjectId", sd.ProjectId);
            var documentDateParam = new SqlParameter("@DocumentDate", sd.Document_Date);
            var documentTypeParam = new SqlParameter("@DocumentType", sd.Document_Type);
            var enteredByIdParam = new SqlParameter("@EnteredById", sd.EnterBy);
            var estimatedParam = new SqlParameter("@Estimated", sd.Estimated);
            var titleParam = new SqlParameter("@Title", sd.Title);
            var codingQATimeParam = new SqlParameter("@CodingQATime", sd.CodingQATime);
            var isCorrectedParam = new SqlParameter("@IsCorrected", sd.IsCorrected);
            var userTaskParam = new SqlParameter("@UserTask", sd.UserTask);
            var isHistoryDocumentParam = new SqlParameter("@isHistoryDocument", sd.isHistoryDocument);
            var returnJSONResultParam = new SqlParameter("@ReturnJSONResult", null);
            // var returnJSONResultParam = new SqlParameter("@ReturnJSONResult", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
            // returnJSONResultParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

            var sql1 = "[dbo].[sp_SaveCodedDatas] {0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9}";

            // Execute the stored procedure

            // Initialize the parameters
            documentIdParam = documentIdParam ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(documentIdParam));
            projectIdParam = projectIdParam ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(projectIdParam));
            documentDateParam = documentDateParam ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(documentDateParam));
            documentTypeParam = documentTypeParam ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(documentTypeParam));
            enteredByIdParam = enteredByIdParam ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enteredByIdParam));
            estimatedParam = estimatedParam ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(estimatedParam));
            titleParam = titleParam ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(titleParam));
            codingQATimeParam = codingQATimeParam ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(codingQATimeParam));
            isCorrectedParam = isCorrectedParam ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(isCorrectedParam));
            userTaskParam = userTaskParam ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userTaskParam));

            var result = dbContext.Set<CodedData>().FromSqlRaw(sql1,
                    documentIdParam.Value,
                    projectIdParam.Value,
                    documentDateParam.Value,
                    documentTypeParam.Value,
                    enteredByIdParam.Value,
                    estimatedParam.Value,
                    titleParam.Value,
                    codingQATimeParam.Value,
                    isCorrectedParam.Value,
                    userTaskParam.Value).ToList();

            var sql = "[dbo].[sp_SaveDcumentAndParties] {0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12},{13},{14},{15},{16}";

            var jsonString = dbContext.JsonResponseResult.FromSqlRaw(sql,
                    actionParam.Value, partiesHistoryJsonParam.Value,
                    exportExtraHistoryJsonParam.Value,
                    fieldSettingsJsonParam.Value,
                    codingSessionDetailsParam.Value,
                    documentIdParam.Value,
                    projectIdParam.Value,
                    documentDateParam.Value,
                    documentTypeParam.Value,
                    enteredByIdParam.Value,
                    estimatedParam.Value,
                    titleParam.Value,
                    codingQATimeParam.Value,
                    isCorrectedParam.Value,
                    userTaskParam.Value,
                    isHistoryDocumentParam.Value,
                    returnJSONResultParam.Value).AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.JsonResponse).FirstOrDefault();

            // Retrieve the output parameter value
            // jsondata = returnJSONResultParam.Value.ToString();

            // Deserialize the JSON string into a JObject dynamically
            JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

            // Create a dictionary to represent the JSON object
            var jsonProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            // Loop through each property in the JObject
            foreach (var property in jsonObject.Properties())
            {
                // Get the name and value of each property
                jsonProperties[property.Name] = property.Value.ToString();
            }

            jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);

            // Explicit refresh
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            // await dbContext.CodedDatas.LoadAsync();
            // await dbContext.Entry(dbContext.CodedDatas).ReloadAsync();

            obj.Information("transaction completed - " + sd.Document_ID);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex) when (IsTransientFailure(ex))
        {
            obj.Information("SaveDocumentAndParties Transient Failure : " + ex.ToString() + ". " + sd.Document_ID);
            jsondata = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                         new { Response = "Transient Failure", Statuscode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message == "Sequence contains more than one element")
            {
                obj.Information("SaveDocumentAndParties : " + ex.ToString() + ". " + sd.Document_ID);
                jsondata = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                             new { Response = "Document Saving fail", Statuscode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError });
            }
            else
            {
                var sqlException = ex.InnerException?.InnerException as SqlException;

                if (sqlException != null)
                    obj.Information("1205 - " + sqlException.Number);

                obj.Information("SaveDocumentAndParties : Main Catch Block. " + sd.Document_ID);
                obj.Information("SaveDocumentAndParties : " + ex.ToString() + ". " + sd.Document_ID);

                jsondata = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                         new { Response = ex.Message, Statuscode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError });
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.Release();
        }
    }

    return Ok(jsondata);
}

In [dbo].[sp_SaveCodedDatas] stored procedure, I am trying to insert data into the Codedatas table and it is successfully saving the record.
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SaveCodedDatas]
    (@DocumentID VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
     @ProjectId VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
     @DocumentDate NVARCHAR(255) = NULL,
     @DocumentType NVARCHAR(255) = NULL,
     @EnteredById INT = NULL,
     @Estimated NVARCHAR(255) = NULL,
     @Title NVARCHAR(4000) = NULL,
     @CodingQATime INT = NULL,
     @IsCorrected INT = NULL,
     @UserTask VARCHAR(10) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    DECLARE @TempCodedDatas AS TABLE (
       [Document_ID] NVARCHAR(255), [Image_File_Name] NVARCHAR(500), [page_label] NVARCHAR(255), [page_num] INT, [num_pages] INT,
       [Coded] INT, [Revision] INT, [DocType] NVARCHAR(255), [EnteredBy] INT, [HostDocId] NVARCHAR(255),
       [ExportDate] DATETIME, [ImportDate] DATETIME, [Percentage] INT, [SetId] INT, [DateCreated] DATETIME, 
       LastModified DATETIME, Host_Reference NVARCHAR(255),[Document_Date] DATETIME, [Estimated] NVARCHAR(255),
       [Document_Type] NVARCHAR(255),Title NVARCHAR(4000), Document_DateValue DATETIME,
       [CodingDate] DATETIME, [CodingTime] INT,[QADate] DATETIME, [QATime] INT, [IsCorrected] INT
    );

     IF @UserTask = 'Coder'
        BEGIN

            INSERT inTO @TempCodedDatas ([Document_ID], [Image_File_Name], [page_label], [page_num], [num_pages], [Coded], [Revision], [DocType], [EnteredBy], [HostDocId],
            [ExportDate], [ImportDate], [Percentage], [SetId], [DateCreated], [LastModified], [Host_Reference], [Document_Date], [Estimated], [Document_Type],
            [Title], [Document_DateValue], [CodingDate], [CodingTime], [IsCorrected])
            SELECT IPS.[Document_ID],IPS.[Image_File_Name],IPS.[page_label],IPS.[page_num],IPS.[num_pages],1 AS [Coded], 
            (CASE WHEN @UserTask='Coder' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS [Revision],@DocumentType AS [DocType],@EnteredById AS [EnteredBy], 
            IPS.[HostDocId],IPS.[ExportDate],IPS.[ImportDate],IPS.[Percentage],IPS.[SetId],IPS.[DateCreated],GETDATE() AS [LastModified], 
            ICD.[Host_Reference], 
            CASE 
                WHEN ISNULL(@DocumentDate, '') = '' THEN NULL 
                ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, @DocumentDate) 
            END AS [DocDate], 
            @Estimated AS [Estimated], 
            @DocumentType AS [Document_Type], 
            CASE 
                WHEN LEN(@Title) > 0 THEN @Title 
                ELSE 'Untitled' 
            END AS [Title], 
            CASE 
                WHEN ISNULL(ICD.Document_DateValue, '') = '' THEN NULL 
                ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, ICD.Document_DateValue) 
            END AS [Document_DateValue], 
            GETDATE() AS [CodingDate], 
            @CodingQATime AS [CodingTime], 
            @IsCorrected AS [IsCorrected]
            FROM
                ImportPages IPS with(nolock)
            INNER JOIN 
                ImportCodedDatas ICD with(nolock) ON ICD.Document_ID = IPS.Document_ID
            WHERE 
                IPS.Document_ID = @DocumentID

            INSERT INTO CodedDatas ([Document_ID], [Image_File_Name], [page_label], [page_num], [num_pages], [Coded], [Revision], [DocType], [EnteredBy], [HostDocId],
            [ExportDate], [ImportDate], [Percentage], [SetId], [DateCreated], [LastModified], [Host_Reference], [Document_Date], [Estimated], [Document_Type],
            [Title], [Document_DateValue], [CodingDate], [CodingTime], [IsCorrected])
            SELECT [Document_ID], [Image_File_Name], [page_label], [page_num], [num_pages],[Coded], [Revision], [DocType], [EnteredBy], [HostDocId],
            [ExportDate], [ImportDate], [Percentage], [SetId], [DateCreated], LastModified, Host_Reference,
            [Document_Date], [Estimated], [DocType],Title, Document_DateValue,[CodingDate], [CodingTime], [IsCorrected]
            FROM @TempCodedDatas

            PRINT 'Coded Data Saved. '+ @DocumentID
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO CodedDatas ([Document_ID], [Image_File_Name], [page_label], [page_num], [num_pages], [Coded], [Revision], [DocType], [EnteredBy], [HostDocId],
            [ExportDate], [ImportDate], [Percentage], [SetId], [DateCreated], [LastModified], [Host_Reference], [Document_Date], [Estimated], [Document_Type],
            [Title], [Document_DateValue], [QADate], [QATime], [IsCorrected])
            SELECT [Document_ID], [Image_File_Name], [page_label], [page_num], [num_pages],[Coded], [Revision], [DocType], [EnteredBy], [HostDocId],
            [ExportDate], [ImportDate], [Percentage], [SetId], [DateCreated], [LastModified], Host_Reference,
            [Document_Date], [Estimated], [DocType],Title, Document_DateValue, [QADate],[QATime], [IsCorrected]
            FROM @TempCodedDatas

            PRINT 'Review Data Saved. '+ @DocumentID
        END;

        Select [Id]
  ,[Document_ID]
  ,[Image_File_Name]
  ,[page_label]
  ,[page_num]
  ,[num_pages]
  ,[Coded]
  ,[Revision]
  ,[DocType]
  ,[EnteredBy]
  ,[HostDocId]
  ,[ExportDate]
  ,[ImportDate]
  ,[Percentage]
  ,[SetId]
  ,[DateCreated]
  ,[LastModified]
  ,[main_id]
  ,[End_Page]
  ,[No_Pages]
  ,[Host_Reference]
  ,[Document_Date]
  ,[Estimated]
  ,[Document_Type]
  ,[Title]
  ,[Document_DateValue]
  ,[CodingDate]
  ,[QADate]
  ,[CodingTime]
  ,[QATime]
  ,[CodingStatus]
  ,[QAStatus]
  ,[IsCorrected]
  ,[IsBackendQA] from CodedDatas

      COMMIT TRANSACTION; -- Inner transaction commit


      END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
      IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; -- Inner transaction rollback
    
      -- Handle the inner catch block
      END CATCH;
END

After execution of the stored procedure when trying to fetch the records from the CodedData table, I get an exception and the data is null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values. In my another procedure for other tables also data is saving but no issue with other tables. Why issue happening for the coded data table?
public class CodedData
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public string Document_ID { get; set; }
    public string Image_File_Name { get; set; }
    public string page_label { get; set; }
    public int page_num { get; set; }
    public int num_pages { get; set; }
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public int Coded { get; set; }
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public int Revision { get; set; }
    public string DocType { get; set; }
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public int? EnteredBy { get; set; }
    public string HostDocId { get; set; }       
    public DateTime? ExportDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ImportDate { get; set; }
    public int Percentage { get; set; }
    public int SetId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
    public string main_id { get; set; }
    public string End_Page { get; set; }
    public int No_Pages { get; set; }
    public string Host_Reference { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Document_Date { get; set; }
    public string Estimated { get; set; }
    public string Document_Type { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Document_DateValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CodingDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? QADate { get; set; }
    public int CodingTime { get; set; }
    public int QATime { get; set; }
    public int IsCorrected { get; set; }
    public string CodingStatus { get; set; }
    public string QAStatus { get; set; }

    public bool? IsBackendQA { get; set; }
}

But when I am truncating the codedatas table, then dbcontext.codeddatas is working.

Which code line throws the exception?

@OlivierJacot-Descombes var result = dbContext.Set().FromSqlRaw(sql1,
documentIdParam.Value,
projectIdParam.Value,
documentDateParam.Value,
documentTypeParam.Value,
enteredByIdParam.Value,
estimatedParam.Value,
titleParam.Value,
codingQATimeParam.Value,
isCorrectedParam.Value,
userTaskParam.Value).ToList();
not only this wherever fetching the dbcontext,codedatas

Side note: you should not use the sp_ prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has reserved that prefix for its own use (see Naming Stored Procedures), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. It's also bad for your stored procedure performance. It's best to just simply avoid sp_ and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

You are doing the null test wrong. For example, titleParam = titleParam ?? throw new ... will only test whether the SqlParameter object is null. But it will never be null, since you assign it with var titleParam = new SqlParameter("@Title", sd.Title);. This does not test whether the parameter value (i.e., titleParam.Value) is null.
Instead directly test the values. E.g.:
var titleParam = new SqlParameter(
    "@Title",
    sd.Title ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sd.Title))
);

Or use this handy method before creating the parameters:
ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(sd.Title, nameof(sd.Title));

Note also that it is not very useful to throw with the name of a local variable, since a local variable is not an input parameter of the current method.
